# Dynamically generated radio buttons share name

Tags: forms, 8

```
   foreach ($questions as $question_index => $question) {

      $form['questions'][$question_index]['answer'] = [
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => '',
        '#default_value' => 1,
        '#options' => $options,
      ];

    }
```

I am generating a form like this, but the radio buttons share the same name. I find that weird since I am wrapping it in a dynamic wrapper.

I know that I could add something along: `[$question_index]['answer_' . $question_index]`

But, is it possible to make it rely on the grouping/container instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using #tree:

```
$form['#tree'] = TRUE;
```

Or you can add it to only your questions element:

```
$form['questions']['#tree'] = TRUE;
```